# My android phone (on 3g ) uses socket to connect to my pc. What Ip should my phone connect to?

Tags: android, sockets

My pc is running a server. The local ip is 192.168.1.4. I know I can find my global ip of my pc in a lot of websites. Say it is ( 201.195.203.25)

But in my android app in real phone, I try to connect to my pc **using socket = new Socket ("201.195.203.25",5000).**

But my pc server dosen't receive any connection. What should I do? Many Thanks!

**Some extra information: the global ip obtained from websites is my router address. My pc is connected to my router.**

Answer (score 4):

Could be a number of issues.

If you're connecting over your phone's 3G connection and your PC is not responding, make sure:

- The port you're trying to connect on (5000 in your question) is open
- Your PC has a server listening for connections on that port
- The server responds the way the app on your phone expects it to

Alternatively...

If you're attempting to connect via USB, that's a whole different can of worms that someone far smarter than me can fill you in on (spoiler alert: it's complicated and messy).

If you're connecting over a wifi network, you'll probably want to use your PC's LAN IP address.

Comment: I think the problems you mentioned are not the causes. Because my emulator can connect to my server perfectly. Maybe because the emulator is on the same network of my server

Comment: I solve the problem now. The solution you need to add a configuration in your router.
I used port forwarding to forward all packets (201.195.203.25:5000 forward to 192.168.1.4:5000 )

Comment: "Make sure the port you're trying to connect on (5000 in your question) is open".